# Mongoose find on field combination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to search on the concatenation of two fields using mongoose.

Something like this from Mysql:

```
select * from CARS where concat(make, model) = "<car name>";
```

Say, I have car schema as below:

```
var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    model: String,
    make: String,
});

var Car =  mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
```

Now is something below possible:

```
Car.find( {make + model : <car name>}, function(err, car) {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) method to do this.

```
Car.aggregate(
    [
        { "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [ 
                { "$eq": [ 
                    { "$concat": [ "$make", " ", "$model" ] },
                    "<car name>"
                ]},
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }}
    ],
    function(err, car) {
        // Do something
    }
)
```